# Tkinter Background Image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am not able to display an image as the background of my GUI window with the below code, any ideas?  I have changed files extension types many times.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()    
window.title("My Application")

lbl = Label(window, text="Hello", font=("arial italic", 25))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)


backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\User 
Person\\Desktop\\months.gif")

label = Label(master=window,
          image = backgroundImage,
          text='This is a test for stackflow',
          height = 2
          )
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code? What does "I am not able" mean?

Comment: "couldn't recognize data in image file" is the error I get.

Comment: That error usually means it's not actually a .gif file. You didn't by any chance take something like a .png or .jpg file and just rename it, did you?

Comment: @Water_Fox, you could use the PIL library as well, to open the image file first. I've just updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to display an image with your code but I used a raw string to define the path for the gif image. You should use it like this:

```
backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User Person\Desktop\months.gif")
```

Notice the `r" "` which makes the image path a raw string, so you don't need to escape the `\`.

I also defined a window geometry:

```
 window.title("My Application")
 window.geometry("320x240")
```

**Update**:

As per comment, you can also use the `PIL` library to open the image first to fix the error `Tkinter error: Couldn't recognize data in image file`:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
backgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\User Person\Desktop\months.gif"))
```

**Note**:

You must also verify that this is a valid gif file. Try opening the file in Windows Picture viewer or similar software. Also, you mentioned that you have changed the file extension, this could make the file unstable and render it invalid. Therefore, make sure you use the original file extension. If you'd like to convert the file to a different format, use specialized software for that or write a simple Python script(although I've never tried this option) that could perform this conversion without breaking the file.